# Cron job posting tweets to twitter with tweetSharp not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter, cron

Very strange problem:

I have a mvc project where I use tweetSharp. It sends tweets to my twitter account as expected.
However, when calling the same url through a cron job, it does not post to twitter, it only do the other tasks in the action result.

So:
If I hit a weblink in in my website (domain.com/scheduler/retweet) throught a normal browser, it grabs data from db, retweet the data, and after retweeting, it update a datetime field in db.

If I call the same url from a cron job (arvixe service), it does not retweet, it only updates the data as if it was retweeted, which tells me that there is nothing wrong with the cron job.

I am doing this every 3 hours in the cron job, none of them worked, if I hit the same url on my browser, I see the tweet on twitter.

It is like if tweeter was filtering posts from cron jobs, but how could they do that?

Comment: Is the cron job logged into Twitter? You are probably logged in via your browser when you do it manually, but the cron job won't be.

Comment: Hi adrianbanks, no it does not require any type of login to access the url. It is a public url. I have tried on different browsers, even using incognito.

Comment: I meant is your cron job logged into Twitter, not do you need to log in to get to the link on your website. You can't retweet something without being logged into Twitter.

Comment: the url that I access generates all the authentication just before it posts to twitter.Country settings = country;
            var service = new TwitterService(settings.twitterConsumerKey, settings.twitterConsumerSecret);
            service.AuthenticateWith(settings.twitterAccessToken, settings.twitterAccessTokenSecret);
            string tweet = string.Format(" in {0} {1}/job/{2}", location, "http://www." + AppConfig.CurrentNETUrl, jobId);
            tweet = tweet.Insert(0, title.Truncate(140 - tweet.Length));
            service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions() { Status = tweet });

Comment: sorry, the code did not look good, but you can see that I am calling a method Authenticate where I pass accesstoken and access token secret.